# Messages cannot flow between client and server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, pygame, multiplayer

I followed the youtube video and used python to make a multiplayer online game of rock-paper-scissors. When I execute the script, the console displays "Couldn't get game", which is generated when the client script does not receive the game sent by the server.
My server script and client script can't seem to exchange information.

This program is not finished yet.
The client script refers to the network script to receive and send messages, and the server script refers to the game script to execute the game.

This is the server script

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import pickle
from game import Game

server = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen()
print("Waiting for connection, Server Started")

connected = set()
games = {}
idCount = 0


def threaded_client(conn, p, gameId):
    global idCount
    conn.send(str.encode(str(p)))

    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(4096).decode()

            if gameId in games:
                game = games[gameId]

                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    if data == "reset":
                        game.resetWent()
                    elif data != "get":
                        game.play(p, data)

                    reply = game
                    conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
            else:
                break
        except:
            break

        try:
            del games[gameId]
            print("Closing game", gameId)
        except:
            pass
        idCount -= 1
        conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)

    idCount += 1
    p = 0
    gameId = (idCount - 1)//2
    if idCount % 2:
        games[gameId] = Game(gameId)
        print("Creating a new game...")
    else:
        games[gameId].ready = True
        p = 1

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, p, gameId))
```

This is the client script

```
import pygame
from network import Network
import pickle
import datetime
pygame.font.init()

width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Client')

class Button:
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, color):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.width = 150
        self.height = 100

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 40)
        text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255,255,255))
        win.blit(text, (self.x + round(self.width/2) - round(text.get_width()/2), self.y + round(self.height/2) - round(text.get_height()/2)))

    def click(self, pos):
        x1 = pos[0]
        y1 = pos[1]
        if self.x <= x1 <= self.x + self.width and self.y <= y1 <= self.y + self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def redrawWindow(win, game, p):
    win.fill((128, 128, 128))

    if not(game.connected()):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
        text = font.render("Wait for Player...", 1, (255,0,0), True)
        win.blit(text, (width/2 - text.get_width()/2, height/2 - text.get_height()/2))
    else:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
        text = font.render("Your Move", 1, (0, 255, 255), True)
        win.blit(text, (80, 200))

        text = font.render("Opponent", 1, (0, 255, 255), True)
        win.blit(text, (380, 200))

        move1 = game.get_player_move(0)
        move2 = game.get_player_move(1)
        if game.bothWent():
            text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0,0,0))
            text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0,0,0))
        else:
            if game.p1Went and p == 0:
                text1 = font.render(move1, 1, (0,0,0))
            elif game.p1Went:
                text1 = font.render("Locked In", 1, (0,0,0))
            else:
                text1 = font.render("Waiting...", 1, (0,0,0))

            if game.p2Went and p == 1:
                text2 = font.render(move2, 1, (0,0,0))
            elif game.p1Went:
                text2 = font.render("Locked In", 1, (0,0,0))
            else:
                text2 = font.render("Waiting...", 1, (0,0,0))

        if p == 1:
            win.blit(text2, (100, 350))
            win.blit(text1, (400, 350))
        else:
            win.blit(text1, (100, 350))
            win.blit(text2, (400, 350))

        for btn in btns:
            btn.draw(win)

        pygame.display.update()


btns = [Button("Rock", 50, 500, (0,0,0)), Button("Scissors", 250, 500, (255,0,0)), Button("Paper", 450, 500, (0,255,0))]
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    n = Network()
    player = int(n.getP())
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(x.strftime("%X"), "You are player", player)

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        try:
            game = n.send("get")
        except:
            run = False
            x = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(x.strftime("%X"), "Couldn't get game")
            break

        if game.bothWent():
            redrawWindow(win, game, player)
            pygame.time.delay(500)
            try:
                game = n.send("reset")
            except:
                run = False
                x = datetime.datetime.now()
                print(x.strftime("%X"), "Couldn't get game")
                break

            font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 90)
            if (game.winner() == 1 and player == 1) or (game.winner() == 0 and player == 0):
                text = font.render("You Won!", 1, (255,0,0))
            elif game.winner == -1:
                text = font.render("Tie Game!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
            else:
                text = font.render("You Lost...!", 1, (255, 0, 0))

            win.blit(text, (width/2 - text.get_width()/2, height/2 - text.get_height()/2))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(2000)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for btn in btns:
                    if btn.click(pos) and game.connected():
                        if player == 0:
                            if not game.p1Went:
                                n.send(btn.text)
                        else:
                            if not game.p2Went:
                                n.send(btn.text)

        redrawWindow(win, game, player)

main()
```

This is the network script.

```
import socket
import pickle

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "240.2.2.1"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.p = self.connect()

    def getP(self):
        return self.p

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
        except socket.error as e:
            str(e)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question you put three scripts network.py client.py server.py.

server.py called "Game" class from "game.py" and you did not put this script, firstly add this file to your project and run server.py, then run client1 and client2 (client2 it's a copy from client1), your code running well in my device after add "game.py" and "client2.py"

You can use the code in the following link, it's from the same source

https://github.com/BigYeser/multiplayer

I also advise you to change the ip address to 127.0.0.1

in server.py

```
server = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5555
```

in network.py

```
self.server = "127.0.0.1"
self.port = 5555
```

Comment: welcome, i will ask you to put my answer as accepted answer if it was useful for you